# What on earth to do with an Oracle .dmp file

Tags: macos, oracle

So I am trying to do some analysis on a dataset that is in an Oracle dump file.  It turns out, as some of you know, that Oracle is no longer supporting (or hosting) any of the binaries for the last version of Oracle that worked on OS X.

I suppose I have a couple options, both of which I might need a bit of help with:

1. Find a link to download Oracle 10 g for Mac OSX.
2. Find a way to load the dumpfile into another DB, say MySQL or Postgres.

Any other ideas/advice?

Answer (score 4):

I'm presuming your problem is that your only available platform is a Mac.  So the obvious solution is to virtualise.  Oracle's Virtualbox is available for various releases in the Mac OSX cattery.  [More out more](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Mac%20OS%20X%20build%20instructions).

Then you can install one of the Oracle appliances.  [Download them here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html).  These appliances are built on Oracle Enterprise Linux but it's not that different from BSD.  I suggest the Database App Developer is the one to use.  It's for 11gR2 but there shouldn't be any problem importing a 10g export file into a later version of the database.

Answer (score 3):

Short of opening a support request with Oracle (which presumes that you have a commercially license for Oracle on Mac), you're probably not going to find a reputable link for old versions of Oracle.  I'd be afraid that any link you find would at least potentially be infected with malware.

A dump file is an Oracle proprietary binary format that Oracle does not document.  I am not aware of any tools to import that data into a non-Oracle database-- I would be surprised if anyone would go to the effort of reverse-engineering that file format.

Can you install Oracle on a Windows or Linux box (potentially a VM running on your Mac)?  That would be the easiest option to import the data.

Answer (score 0):

The dmp file is a proprietary format. I doubt you will be able to import into another database.